# RabbitMq AutorecoveringChannels are getting collected in memory even though those are being closed in the code

Tags: java, rabbitmq

In my RabbitMQ RPC application, I am using one RabbitMQ connection and channel per each message being published. So, the channel is being closed once the message is responded with a result. Pretty straightforward application.

Even though I close the channels(I monitored runtime logs and make sure all the channels are being closed), the AutorecoveringChannel object instances are getting collected and being grown in the memory. I am not sure why this happens. Since I expect RabbitMQ client to wipe off all the data and the channels once the channel is being closed.

I searched in google and everywhere to know why, but every article is telling just to close the channel that is it. For an idea, please check this screenshot of VisualVM results of growing objects.

```
 Object                                               instances

 com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel    249
 com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecordedQueue            502
 com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecordedQueueBinding     502
 com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareChannelN    255
```

This is how I create the channel in each and every message received thru web sockets

```
    Channel channel = rabbitMqController.getRmqConnection().createChannel();

    //some code

    DefaultConsumer consumer = getConsumer(methodCall, channel, callbackFunction);

    //some code

    channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);
    channel.basicConsume(statusReplyQueueName, true, consumer);
    channel.basicPublish(WorkerConfig.getInstance().getWorkerExchangeName(), methodCall.getMethod(), true, props,
            methodCall.toJson());
```

And in the getConsumer() I am closing the channel like this once the message responded.

```
        return new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                                   byte[] body) throws IOException {

            closeChannel(channel);
            //handling code goes here
        }
```

closeChannel is simply channel.close().

Please share your idea with me if you can guess anything that happens here. Even small suggestions which will make me in the right track on this memory issue, are happily welcome.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @Vlad yes, I switched off autoRecovering channels and implemented my own recovering mechanism.

Comment: Yay! I got to the same solution yesterday and worked :D